# Is there a way to completely block the ability to take screenshots in Android?

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-capture

I'm currently developing a light-weight application where in one part of the app I would like to COMPLETELY take away the ability to take a screenshot in Android. When I say screenshot, I'm talking about iPhone's "screen capture" feature. This is for security reasons.  I realize there are apps out there that allow users in Android to do this as well, and I want to block this functionality. Any way of doing this is fine, whether disabling the hardware buttons, freezing the phone, or via software.

Comment: For ICS and up, have you tried [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html)? For everything older, mileage will vary since there wasn't a standard screenshot implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the window LayoutParam `FLAG_SECURE`. Add this to your `onCreate` method:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

More on this topic can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background).

Answer (score 0):

Add an application class in your project like that to prevent the full app from screen-shot (*All Activity and Fragment around your app*). This is the [example project](https://github.com/Gkemon/Full-App-ScreenShot-Protection-Android) and below I mentioned the core code -

```
public class MyApplicationContext extends Application {

    private  Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        setupActivityListener();
    }

    private void setupActivityListener() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```