# Need to hide content of program from Android "Overview Screen"

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android app for a security-conscious employer. He's concerned about the screen snapshot that appears on the [Overview Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html#attr-doclaunch) (a.k.a. the recent-tasks list) leaking sensitive information, and wants me to put up the program's splash screen before the system takes that picture. Unfortunately I haven't found any way to do so.

Things I've tried:

- Inflate the splash screen's View in the `onPause` function. (No effect, even with `bringToFront` and `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.)
- Inflate the splash screen's View in `onCreate` and use `bringToFront` in `onPause`. (Again, no effect.)
- Calling `setVisible(false)` in `onPause`. (Seemed to almost work, in that the screen blinks to black for an instant when switching away from the program, but it's apparently made visible by the system again before the snapshot.)
- Calling `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on the topmost item of the View in `onPause`. (Seems like it will work, but the snapshot is apparently taken before it takes effect.)

I'm a moderately accomplished Android developer, but I can't help but feel that there's a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Try [`onCreateThumbnail()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateThumbnail%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Canvas%29), as I think that's what is used here. Or, [use `FLAG_SECURE`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html) to simply block everything (versus the splash screen).

Comment: @CommonsWare, perfect! If you'll turn that into an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Personally, I would [go with `FLAG_SECURE`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html), and simply block display of this stuff everywhere:

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                         LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```

However, IIRC, you can override `onCreateThumbnail()` to supply your own image to use for the recent-tasks list. Note that this might have changed with Android 5.0, as they have overhauled that recent-tasks list, so be sure to test your code on a 5.0 device or emulator.

Comment: Unfortunately `onCreateThumbnail` doesn't seem to work. It's never called here (Android 4.4 and 5.0), and I found this: <https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29370>. `FLAG_SECURE` also has its own troubles, as partly described here: <http://stackoverflow.com/a/11121897/12193>. Ah well, keep calm and carry on. ;-)

Comment: Add FLAG_SECURE and i user can't screen shot the app. I just want to hide content app, how can i do it. Thank you.

Comment: @JackHuynh: Sorry, but I do not know what "hide content app" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare, its same messenger of face book, when app go to background, it have a mask to security the app.

Comment: @JackHuynh: Sorry, but I do not know of a reliable way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution for hiding content of an app by covering it with a splash screen when the app is put into the background. 
This is not using the FLAG_SECURE technique, I simply override the onPause and onResume methods of the screens and modify the view to show one that covers everything in the back.

First I create my splash screen in a separate file as a relative layout called splash_screen_custom, I also give the relative layout in the file an id customSplash. Note the elevation setting, I ran into an issue where buttons have a preset elevation, so by setting this cover screen to have a high elevation it will cover any buttons(of course you don't need this if you are not covering buttons).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
     android:id="@+id/customSplash"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
     android:elevation="5dp"
         >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="202dp"
         android:layout_height="157dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/yourImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In this example my screen I am trying to cover is a relative layout so I am able to simply add and delete my splash screen to it via the addView and removeView methods of view I am trying to cover.

```
override fun onPause() {

    var parentView = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parentView)
    var splashScreen = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.splash_screen_custom, null)
    parentView.addView(splashScreen, parentView.width, parentView.height)

    super.onPause()

}

override fun onResume() {
    var parentView = findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.parentView)
    parentView.removeView(findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.customSplash))
    super.onResume()

}
```

Comment: Slight bug I realized after.... This will cause the transition to screens to show splash screen in between transition as well (obviously since onPause will be called). You can simply create a flag to disable for specific intents. This is not as clean as I would like it to be. However if you really need the splash screen when putting the app in the background, this is the cleanest way I have found.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @D.Maul 's answer but the Java version, instead of adding a view, I have tried this. It works fairly but sometimes the recent snapshot shows the app content not sure what to do about it.

```
private Dialog dialog = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light);
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlaunch);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    dialog.show();
    super.onPause();
}
    
@Override
protected void onResume() {
     dialog.hide();
     super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to provide another version for **react-native** android based on @D.Maul 's answer:

Bug on some edge cases:

- [1] Dialog is showing
- [2] A very quick SplashScreen is shown when open Camera

Code

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  try {
    // Hide app preview with SplahScreen
    FrameLayout parentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (parentView != null && parentView.findViewById(R.id.splash_activity) == null) {
      View splashScene = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.splash_activity, null);
      parentView.addView(splashScene, parentView.getWidth(), parentView.getHeight());
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // do nothing
  }

  super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  try {
    // Remove SplashScreen
    FrameLayout parentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if (parentView != null) {
      parentView.removeView(this.findViewById(R.id.splash_activity));
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // do nothing
  }

  super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Hi @tran
This seems to work most of the time on my emulator, but on my physical OnePlus 8 Pro it never works. I tried to remove the onResume call to verify that the splash screen is actually being rendered, which it is. It might be a timing/performance issue then, a race between taking the screenshot and rendering the overlay. I find it frustrating that Android removed their API (onCreateThumbnail) for setting the thumbnail and don't provide another solution for it. Was above really working for you on physical devices too?

Comment: Hi, yes last time I tested it work on my pixel 2. But I don't use this because of those edge cases above. I use FLAG_SECURE now for better security because it is handled by OS. example: `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`

Comment: Yeah, we do that at the moment, but our users are complaining about not being able to take screenshots (I understand them), and we were just allowed to enable this, but now this might be a show stopper.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of launching an activity, you might consider launching an app task using `ActivityManager.addAppTask(Activity, Intent, ActivityManager.TaskDescription, Bitmap)`, with which the bitmap you passed in is used as the thumbnail in the overview/recent screen.

Document on this api is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#addAppTask(android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)), however, it's only available in Lollipop.

Comment: That example code, doesn't work