# how to disable screenshot on android p

Tags: android, screenshot

Currently i am using FLAG_SECURE method to disable the screenshot functionality but users having **Android P** are able to take screenshots. How to restrict that?

**This is not working for Android P:
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only method available as of now. No official documentation is available. You might have to do some hack or other non traditional methods which I am not aware of, sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52976001/6142219 -> maybe this helps

Comment: i am using the same, and i have android P. it works for me without any issue.. Whenever user takes screenshot (even with 3rd party apps), it gives black screen

Comment: @Deepakkaku the solution suggested by you wont work. Read the comment under that post.

Comment: @Sam. have you tried on One plus with Android 9 . and whats the status in this case?

Comment: @AkanshaGoel i have not tried in One plus (Oxygen OS). But i tried and it works fine for Lineage OS, MI, Asus, Samsung devices.. so it must work for one plus... don't know how it is not working for you.. or may be it is cause of oxygen os..