# How to show splash-screen on Multiview in a Ionic 3 app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic 3 app (can't update right now) and am using [Cordova Plugin Splashscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) to show the app's splash-screen.

Ideally when the user clicks the Overview (the one on the right) for multiview to see all active apps my app would show a splash screen instead of the current data on the app. I could not find this in the documentation but I think I might not be using the right names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling I found a `FLAG_SECURE` flag you could use, but it seems to break the app for some devices/Android versions.

Sources:

- [How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)
- [Need to hide content of program from Android "Overview Screen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284778/need-to-hide-content-of-program-from-android-overview-screen)

A better option would probably be to listen to the [`pause`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause) and [`resume`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#resume) events and manually hide/show your content or overlay an image.