# Hide screenshot for App Switcher in FMX iOS App

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

In a mobile iOS system, when double-pressing on the home button, the user will enter an App Switcher, a series of App windows will be displayed. If your own App window has sensitive info, it can be leaked at this stage.

I have managed to use `FMX.Platform` to catch different App events. I was trying to change to another `TabItem` instead of a sensitive `TabItem`. My code can compile, but the display on iOS still remains the same. The code looks like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  aFMXApplicationEventService: IFMXApplicationEventService;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXApplicationEventService, IInterface(aFMXApplicationEventService)) then
    aFMXApplicationEventService.SetApplicationEventHandler(HandleAppEvent)
  else
    ShowMessage('Application Event Service is not supported.');
end;

...

function TForm1.HandleAppEvent(AAppEvent: TApplicationEvent; AContext: TObject): Boolean;
begin      
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.aeWillBecomeInactive then begin
    tempActiveTbaItem := TabControl1.TabIndex;
    TabControl1.TabIndex := 4; //4 is a blank tabItem
    TabControl1.UpdateEffects;
  end else
  if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.aeEnteredBackground then begin
    tempActiveTbaItem := TabControl1.TabIndex;
    TabControl1.TabIndex := 4;
  end else
  if (AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.aeBecameActive) and (tempActiveTbaItem <> -1) then begin
    TabControl1.TabIndex := 0;
  end;
    
  Result := True;
end;
```

I googled the web and found two solutions here:

[Making sensitive data disappear in the iOS/iPadOS App Switcher](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/12/16/making-sensitive-data-disappear-in-the-ios-ipados-app-switcher/)

[Hide Sensitive Information in the iOS App Switcher Snapshot Image](https://hacknicity.medium.com/hide-sensitive-information-in-the-ios-app-switcher-snapshot-image-25ddc9b8ef5f)

But these are for the native Xcode only.  Can someone tell me how to do it in Delphi for FMX, please?

Comment: What does your current code look like that is not working for you?

Comment: Hi Remy. The code is working, but APP SWITCHER won't change the view . this is the problem. It seems it needs another iOS native function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iOS, this should resolve the problem:

```
uses
  FMX.Platform.iOS;

// Other code snipped

if AAppEvent = TApplicationEvent.aeWillBecomeInactive then
begin
  tempActiveTbaItem := TabControl1.TabIndex;
  TabControl1.TabIndex := 4; //4 is a blank tabItem
  WindowHandleToPlatform(Handle).View.setNeedsDisplay;
end;
```

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` forces the view to repaint

Comment: Beautifully working!!! for iOS. Will it work on Android as well?

Comment: It does not look possible to implement on Android, since it appears that the `onPause` of the `Activity` needs to be overridden, and the action taken *before* the inherited (`super`) `onPause` is called, as per [examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284778/need-to-hide-content-of-program-from-android-overview-screen). Currently in Delphi the WillBecomeActive event is sent after the `onPause` has already occurred, in which Android has taken a snapshot of your screen (with the sensitive data).

Comment: I've filed a report about it in the Quality Portal: http://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34252

Comment: You are a star. Hopefully it can be a true crossplatform feature soon. Thanks