# Prevent screen capture in Unity Android app

Tags: android, android-activity, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a Unity Android plugin to prevent screenshots while running the app. I read the following.

[How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)

From what I have read I need to call the following in the Activity onCreate handler....

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

But I have not been able to get this to work. I have tried extending UnityPlayerActivity, UnityPlayerNativeActivity, and even android.app.NativeActivity. I have verified that the plugin itself is working properly (I am able to call other functions in the plugin) and the onCreate method is getting executed.

I have tried setting the flags in multiple places inside onCreate, such as before and/or after setContentView(mUnityPlayer), but it never works.

I'm testing on an HTC One m8. Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your onCreate() method:

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

The problem might be your reference, this worked fine when I tested it:

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
  }
}
```