# Distorted screen with certain intent/phone combo

Tags: android, android-intent, graphics, android-asynctask

In my app there's a point where new intent is created that performs a asynctask. Problem is, on one specific phone a distorted picture appears (Android 2.3.6 on Samsung GT-S6102).

[image: Distorted picture with loading ring visible]

As you can see, there is supposed to be loading circle on a white background. After it finishes I get various different distorted screens, sometimes just black screen.

[image: more scrambled screens :S]

From pc experience I'd say this is hardware issue but I can't be sure. On a side-note: this model's camera can't be forced into portrait mode, which this app does and so the camera looks horrible on screen. Is there any possibility that these issues are related (in the previous intent, the camera was used)?

EDIT: I have realised, that the cause is the following code

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: bumb :S any input would help

Comment: I'd say that bothering any pre 4.x version of Android is usually waste of time nowadays: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Comment: Found answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background

Comment: ok, closed as duplicate then.