# Is there any way to show splashScreen when app is in the background or switching tabs. In ionic 6?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs, switching

I use privacy-screen plugin to hide content when app is in the background, but it shows just gray background. I need to set splashScreen instead. Any suggestions?

I tried splashScreen plugin, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way but I think that using Capacitor `appStateChange` from `@capacitor/app` ([documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app)) you could show and hide a screen with your logo when app is in background or foreground.

```js
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('appStateChange', ({ isActive }) => {
  console.log('App state changed. Is active?', isActive);
  if(!isActive) showLogoScreen();
  else hideLogoScreen();
});
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you Miguel for your answer, I tried and it is not working for me, unfortunately!

Comment: Ohhh, sorry. You can also try the library [@capacitor/splash-screen](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen) and maybe using it with `appStateChange` you can approach it.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, I did it simply in native code: just find the "applicationWillResignActive" method in AppDelegate and insert a view on top of the window.

For Android, sadly I couldn't find a better solution. The "gray background" you described is likely the implementation of [Hide screen in 'Recent Apps List', but allow screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642642/hide-screen-in-recent-apps-list-but-allow-screenshots)