# How do I prevent an Android device from a taking a screenshot of my webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, android

I am currently working on a webpage.  One of the requirements is to prevent any **ANDROID DEVICE** from taking a screenshot of the said page.  I found this block of codes but this is in Java.  Is there any equivalent javascript or php code for this?  Can a webpage detect if a mobile device (Android) is trying to take a screenshot?

```
public class FlagSecureTestActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);
   }
}
```

Source:  [How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do by just having a web page.
If you have this requirement, you will also have to make a native android browser also.

Comment: If it couldn't be prevented, then is there any ways or means to make it a bit complicated or difficult for the user to screenshot the page?

Comment: Nothing can be done there as a web page, sorry.
Screenshot is a OS level feature and if you need to prevent it, you atleast need a native app running. Browsers by default allow screenshots.