# How to block screenshot using JS on Mobile iOS/Android?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, screenshot

I'm trying to stop the screenshot event on mobile using JavaScript, because on PC is easier, I used only the event keyCode == 44 to stop.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can't. You can't do it on PC either. There's too many different ways to take pictures of the screen, including literally taking a picture of the screen. Even if you did implement something using JS, it could just be disabled using the console.

Comment: Heh. You didn't block anything on the PC. It's trivial to go around whatever blocks you try to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent an Android device from a taking a screenshot of my webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099410/how-do-i-prevent-an-android-device-from-a-taking-a-screenshot-of-my-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prevent user from taking screenshots with Flags in Android

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

There is another solution for IOS devices where you can prevent taking screenshots programatically but I don't think there is a solution with JS.

EDIT: Those solutions for the **applications** not for a website!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, hence screenshot thing is iOS native features and independent to any app, you can not stop taking screenshot by coding for app.