# Prevent Screenshots for particular activity in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-screen-support

i searched about the screenshot prevention. i found a answer but it blocks the screenshot for all activities in a app. but i need to block screenshots for specific activity.

Referring the below answer couldn't helped.

[How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)

Comment: I don't see how the accepted answer to the question you linked to doesn't answer your question. In what way was it unclear?

Answer (score 3):

**Use below code in `onCreate()` of your `Activity`:**

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
                     LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

above code work for particular activity also.If you 
do not work this code then other problem there may be import of layout param wrong or place of code wrong.

Be careful about using `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`, on some devices, this will make the view scrambled. Looks like a Samsung specific bug. I recommend the following:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Comment: after executing this code i can get the screenshot but after sometime i can't get the screenshot. why delay?

Comment: which device used and android version..?

Comment: may be some device's specific bug

Comment: samsung galaxy s6 5.1.1

Comment: may be not working in galaxy s6. check in other device