# Prevent taking a screenshot in android

Tags: android, screenshot, android-screen-support

i used the below link to prevent to take screenshot but this will take more time  to prevent taking the screenshot after executing the code which is going to prevent the taking of screenshot.

[How do I prevent Android taking a screenshot when my app goes to the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background)

Code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Phone: galaxy s6
Os: 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

This code is intended to mark an `Activity` (or more precise, a Window) as "Secure" not the phone. It only prevents the `Activity` in which this flag has been set from having its screenshot taken.

To secure an `Activity`, call this code in the `OnCreate`. This will not stop screenshots when the `Activity` is not displayed.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

}
```

I haven't tried it myself so do not know if it is possible but you could perhaps draw an invisible window on top of the current Activity that has the SECURE flag set. Maybe this would prevent screenshots of the whole phone which I think is what you are asking.

Comment: It doesn't work to prevent screenshots whilst in the background but I already stated that. It does work for its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Before your setContentView() method.