# Need to Hide information in an activity or a fragment when app running in background

Tags: android, android-configchanges, android-security

[image]

i am using one app, for example chrome with some confidential information and i am switching it to background & i am trying to **kill** the app.

i uploaded the example image when trying to kill the app. even the session the expired it won't close the information in the **killing stage** when app comes foreground then only it closes the information. i want the info should be closed or hided when it goes **background (In killing stage)**.

i searched in google i am not getting anything related to this and i don't know whether my search phrase is correct. can anyone pleas help me.

Comment: r u developing app ?

Comment: yes.. for example i am posting it... @Learner

Comment: how you are going do this? this is android default property and i think it is not so essay to change

Comment: I don't know how to do just asking suggestions. @Sree

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background

Comment: i think it is not duplicate its about the reading information even though session expired & when app in background (During killing the app) @SachinRao

Comment: @user3546693 : it may contain answers which may be possible solutions this one

Comment: @user3546693 did my answer helps mean u just accept or comment what ur getting error :(

Answer (score 5):

I think ur asking this:

Just add this in manifest file:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Example:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:taskAffinity=".OnInviteActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

then your app will not show in background or recent app or in menu like that

UPDATE:

for ur app name only u need to add this in Main Activity:

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: Yeah thank you... but it closes the apps from recently used list i want the content or information to be hided, only the title or header part can be visible.

Comment: @user3546693 check this it may helps u