# Change screen shot in task switcher

Tags: android

I am writing an app that when I press the home button then go to the app switcher as in the picture below, I want to be able to set the screenshot or hide the screenshot of my app in the list so that you can not see the information of my app. ie like you can see the map in the picture below. Any ideas would be great.

Task switcher image:

[image]

Comment: To block the screenshot, [use `FLAG_SECURE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background/9822607?s=3|0.4450#9822607). I don't think that there is a working solution for replacing the screenshot, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks worked great.