# How can I show an overlay on my app when I click the "Recent Apps" button?

Tags: java, android, view

I am developing a HIPAA compliant Android app, which requires that all private or sensitive information displayed on the app be hidden when the user taps the "recent apps" button on an Android phone.

I can show an overlay with no issue, but I can't figure out how to capture when the user taps the "Recent Apps" button on the phone.

I have tried putting this code in my base activity: 
if

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (!hasFocus) {
        if(mInflatedView == null) {
            mInflatedView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.background_overlay, null);
        }

        WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        wlp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        wlp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        wlp.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mInflatedView, wlp);
    }
}
```

which will display an overlay correctly. However, the method `onWindowFocusChanged(false)` is actually called **after** the app screenshot is rendered in the "recent apps" expose view.

Does anyone have any idea how to capture user clicks on the "recent apps" button **before** the OS brings the apps to the exposed view?

Comment: "which requires that all private or sensitive information displayed on the app be hidden when the user taps the "recent apps" button on an Android phone" -- [use `FLAG_SECURE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/115145). Not only is your approach not possible AFAIK, it doesn't cover screenshots.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you! I hadn't heard of `FLAG_SECURE`. Exactly what I was looking for, and a lot simpler to implement. Post this as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Well, technically, it's a duplicate, so I marked it as such. Be sure to test your app thoroughly, though, as `FLAG_SECURE` has small but unfortunate holes. I mention this in that answer, pointing to [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/06/06/psa-flag-secure-window-leaks.html) which, in turn, points to [this analysis and workarounds](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/docs/FLAGSECURE.md).