# ionic 2: How to change the thumbnail/snapshot for recent apps list?

Tags: ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

For some security reasons I don't want to show the content of the app when it is listed in recent apps list.

I tried to add an opaque overlay over the page in onPause event trigger but it is too late. Snapshot is taken before the onPause event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add the template code snippet removing the sensitive info that you don't want to share. Otherwise it's difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via HTML code, instead set the **FLAG_SECURE** while launching the Main Activity in the Android Code (Java). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background) on how to apply this flag!