# Why set FLAG_SECURE before setContentView()?

Tags: android, screenshot

When trying to look up how to block screenshots on Android, I noticed that many sites suggest[0] setting `FLAG_SECURE` on the window and *before* calling `setContentView()`.

I have been trying to understand why, but I'm not able to find anything. Looking at the source code for `Window.setFlags()`, I can't see any difference `Activity.setContentView()` would make.

[0]: example: https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/01/16/secure-against-screenshots.html , https://stackoverflow.com/a/29164604/1574325

Comment: You have to set the window flags before calling `setContentView()`. Otherwise, you will get an exception. As to "why" beyond that, I have no idea. I treat it as "just one of those things" and move along to other work... :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare, interesting: I don't see an exception, but my use is slightly different: I have an activity, which has a fragment, inside of which is a ViewPager of images. In the view pager, there might be certain items that I don't want the user screenshotting, so when such an item shows, I do: `fragment.getActivty().getWindow().addFlags(FLAG_SECURE)`. 

This does not throw an exception, but doesn't work on some older devices. I wonder if they're related that way.

Comment: Hmmm... perhaps it's only some flags that you need to set before `setContentView()`. I'm really sure that there are scenarios where calling `addFlags()` after `setContentView()` throws an exception.