# Hide app screenshot in multitasking view prior to API 17 Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I have successfully used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/6316091) to prevent my app content from being displayed on the multitasking view. I have adapted it for Xamarin.

This is my current solution :

```
public class MyActivity : FragmentActivity
{

    [...]

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        OverridePendingTransition(Resource.Animation.anim_in, Resource.Animation.anim_out);
        Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
    }

    [...]

}
```

This works well on recent devices.

My question is : How do I get a similar behaviour on devices prior to Android API 17?

The [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE) mentions this flag was added in API 17, but doesn't mention any workaround for older versions. I need to support down to Android 4.0.3 (API 15) ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually using [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) from `WindowManagerFlags` that were introduced in API level 1. Display flag [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#FLAG_SECURE) introduced in API level 17 is a different thing and I don't see you using it in your code. In conclusion, you should be just fine on API level 15 with the current implementation.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I didn't see the difference between the two

Comment: @GabrielBourgault No wonder, same name and VERY similar usage doesn't help! :)