# How to prevent the Screentshot in the entire android app without repeating the same code

Tags: android, android-security, android-application-class

Hi everyone i want to block the Screenshot in my app. I got the first problem solve [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background).

But now the thing is I have more than 10 activity and 10 + fragment.

**Is there any way to do this just  by writing in the one class and giving it reference to the entire app.**

**Just like we make one Application class and in the AndroidMainfest.xml give that application class refrence.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a BaseActivity, and make all your activities extend this `BaseActivity`. In `onCreate()` of this activity set the flag. You need to ensure all your activities call `super.onCreate()` as follows:

`BaseActivity.java`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set your flag here
        ...
    }
}
```

`Activity1.java`

```
public class Activity1 extends BaseActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Studio is giving me the warning BaseActivity not registered in the AndroidMainfest.xml. Does i am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: you can mark it as `abstract`. This will ensure you don't accidentally run `BaseActivity` stand-alone. See updated answer.

Comment: i have learned this in my college but unable to apply the same . Thanks buddy i have understood the same. cheers :)

Comment: can we block SS in Fragment also i have fragment also in my app

Comment: I think if you apply to host activity, then it should be cascaded to fragment. In case its not, you should be able to do the same with Fragments as you do with Activity i.e. create `BaseFragment`