# How to stop the app in this window (see pictures)?

Tags: android, background

Hello everybody I wrote a Android-App and it works fine but there is one problem that I want to solve. My problem is I don't want the app working like this (see picture 1)  you know you can go to last apps (like picture 2 ) and open app in the little window. My question is how to stop my app when someone is doing it .(I'm  very sorry about my English,I'm still learning . I hope you understand it guys ). Thank you in advance.

picture1
[image: picture1]
picture2
[image: picture2]

Comment: you want to close your app if someone minimizes it?

Comment: yes that what i want :)

Comment: maybe not close but stop or something like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set`android:noHistory` in manifest of your activity to true as follows if you want to want to avoid user revisiting your app:

```
 <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"/>
```

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#nohist):

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

**Looking at your image, looks like you want to disable the multi-window support:**

You need to set following flag:

`android:resizeableActivity="false"` in you application as follows:

```
<application 
   android:resizeableActivity="false" >
    . . .
</application>
```

This will disable the multi-window support for your entire app. If you just want a particular activity for which this should be disabled, then you can:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...
    android:resizeableActivity="false" />
```

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` in your `onCreate()` method.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/9723698

Comment: i will try it :)