# Android View visibility changes while it is in background (Task switcher)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I am trying to show a different view when the app is browsed in task switcher. This is achieved via a fragment that is attached to the activity.

```
class ProtectorFragment: Fragment(){
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, ...): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_protector...)
   }

  override fun onResume() {
      super.onResume()
      background.visibility = View.GONE
  }

  override fun onPause() {
      super.onPause()
      background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
  }
}
```

However, it doesn't work as expected in Android 6,7 & 10 devices. Protector view appears for a second and disappears. No View.GONE / INVISIBLE calls are made.

[image: View that is protected]

[image: Protector View on top as soon as app hit background]

[image: Protector View is gone after a second]

But, what is more confusing is, Layout inspector shows the protector view. But, device shows a view that is underneath the Protector view. And, the bottom navigation view also always on top whatever the elevation I set.

[image: What Layout inspector shows all the time the app is in bg]

Any clues?

[Github link](https://github.com/cocoBavan/protectionFragment)

Comment: The preview in the task switcher is not live. The system is showing a screenshot of the UI when the app was paused. If you want to avoid this screenshot to be shown you can use the [FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE). Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background).

Comment: Thank you. So, there is no way i could show my custom screenshot? When i searched, it seems they have completely removed the ability to add custom screenshots, yet I see lot of banking applications secure their apps in bg with custom screenshots. Anyway, thanks again for your input.