# How to hide Android application from remote Device Access like TeamViewer

Tags: android, security, remote-access

I want to hide our Android application from remote Device Access like TeamViewer, anyDesk for security reasons.

Requirement is when user phone is given for remote access, if my application is opens then other person has to see black screen instead of my app.

For example:-
In `Mobile A` has my app let's say `ABC App`, Now `Mobile A` given remote access to `Mobile B`.Now when `Mobile A` opens `ABC App` then `Mobile B` has to see black screen instead of `ABC App`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822607/115145

Comment: This is not database content or data. Actually i don't want share my app screen to remote access tools. @CommonsWare

Comment: "i don't want share my app screen to remote access tools" -- use `FLAG_SECURE`, as I indicated in my linked-to answer.

Comment: I already tried this `FLAG_SECURE` flag using like this ```getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);``` 
But this flag prevent to take screenshot. @CommonsWare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `FLAG_SECURE` does not work (it is blocking screenshots and screencasts but not blocking a particular remote-support app), then the remote-support app vendor has partnered with the device manufacturer for low-level access (e.g., direct access to framebuffers). There are no defenses against this.

The best that you can do is try to come up with a blacklist of apps, use `PackageManager` to see if any of those apps are installed, and refused to show various screens in your app until the user uninstalls those other apps.

Comment: Thank you so much i wasted my 2 days on it to figure out this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The best that you can try `getWindow().getWindowManager()` before `setContentView()` on Activity which you don't want to share. This will  protect the screen.